# Is there a PPA for gdb 7.4?

Tags: ppa

Is there a way to install gdb 7.4 on Ubuntu 10.04 using `apt-get`? There is some sort of bug with gdb 7.1 that shows up with a program I am debugging.

I downloaded and compiled gdb 7.4 from source and that fixed the problem for me.  But I would like to update all of my systems to use gdb 7.4 if possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was about to make one for you, but there is one I found while doing that.

Here you go: https://code.launchpad.net/~nitrof22/+archive/ppa